# How to resolve the dependency of `highline`

Tags: gnome-terminal, dependencies, ruby

I am new to Ubuntu and I wanna use `RHC`, so I followed the steps from this http://openshift.com/get-started and Installed:

1. Ruby
2. Ruby Gems
3. Git

And after that I am executing this command from the Terminal:

`sudo gem install rhc`

So it executes for some time and it output's

`Unable to resolve dependencies: commander requires highline(~>1.7.1); rhc requires highline (~> 1.6.1)`

Please Help, I really need to make this work.
Thanks 
 Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because rhc and commander requires different versions of highline.
Try this:

```
sudo gem install highline --version 1.7.1
sudo gem install highline --version 1.6.1
```